# Match a single $ or camelCase words

Tags: regex, lint, eslint

```
^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

I use the above RegExp to match camelCase words, but I also want to match a single $.

How can I do that?

The results that I want:

- **$** - This should match.
- **$$** or **$camelCase** - This shouldn’t match.
- **camelCase** - This should match.
- **_camelCase** - This shouldn’t match.
- **characters_characters** - This shouldn’t match.

Thank you!

Comment: your regex should match `fooo` also. If you don't want , then `^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alternation operator. Since `$` is a special regex character, you need to escape that.

```
^(?:[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)*|\$)$
```

The above regex works, but I had to use the one below because ESLint was complaining about the escaped character.

```
^(?:[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*|[$])$
```

Comment: It seems that my linting utility (ESLint) doesn’t like this RegExp. “Error: unknown escape sequence at line...” Any alternatives?

Comment: @user557108 this should work also, `^(?:[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*|\\$)$`

Comment: Avinash Raj - No, it only matches camelCase, and I also want to match a single $.